# Motor controlled using Rpi 3 and 12V power supply

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

Could someone please assist me with the below circuit? I can't seem to get it to work. I am using a 12V power supply and Raspberry Pi 3. Apologies, I am very new to circuits. The DC motor does not turn on, when I run my script.

[image: photo of breadboard]

[image: schematic]

Motor specification:

- Operating Voltage : Between 6 V and 18 V
- Nominal Voltage : 12 V
- Free-run speed at 12 V : 22 RPM
- Free-Run Current at 12 V : 50 mA
- Stall Current at 12 V : 1200 mA
- Stall Torque at 12 V : >24 kg·cm
- Gear Ratio : 1:377
- Reductor Size : 27 mm
- Weight : 94 g

Comment: Your PN2222 may be too small to run your motor. What is the motor rating? Perhaps try a larger BJT.

Comment: @wes - Welcome :-) What troubleshooting have you done so far? Please [edit the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/551106/edit) to add those details (don't add them as comments below). Examples of useful info would be voltage measurements (relative to ground) at the correct RPi GPIO pin when the motor should be on & when it should be off; also voltage measurements at the transistor collector for the same two tests. Your schematic shows the transistor as PN2222 - those are usually plastic, but the photo shows a metal can. What is the transistor type? Is it connected correctly?

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? Can you measure the voltages across each component when you run your script? If so, please tell us what you measured.

Comment: 2N2222s are available in the TO-18 "Full Metal Jacket" and those are rated for 800 mA. Test your circuit by putting R1 on 5V instead of the GPIO. If it works there, it's the software. If not... Hardware problem.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser = Hi, "*2N2222s are available in the TO-18 "Full Metal Jacket"*" Yes! But the schematic shows **PN2222** which is the plastic one, isn't it? With the different pinout IIRC. I'm just trying to get more info from the OP to eliminate the possibility of incorrect transistor pinout. We can't tell from the photo so far... See what I mean? Also 800mA seems low for the possible start current on that motor, but again, all depends on the actual transistor part number. I'm just fairly sure that it doesn't match the schematic, whatever p/n it really is :-)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will buy a multimeter tomorrow. The transistor is a 2n2222a (CDIL, M9). I have also tried the 5v PIN and that doesn't work, so I must be setting it up incorrectly.

Comment: Am I correct in saying the negative from the power supply is the 0VDC running to the ground and emitter as per the bottom of the schematic?

Comment: Here is a test you can try. Turn on your motor programmatically, then spin the shaft of the motor to see if it runs. If the motor runs continuously after a spin start, you don't have enough starting current.

Comment: Welcome! Also, if you hook the motor up to the 12 V directly, does it run? Just want to make sure it's not dead first. And I echo what people are saying above - the motor might need more current than the 2222 can provide. The comment above me has a good tip to test that - while the code is running, try "helping" the motor by twisting it a little bit by hand and see if it starts up. That's a sign there's not enough current.

Comment: @wes - Hi, Re: "*Expected voltage is 5.08 V from the Rpi power PIN. I got this throughout the whole circuit including the transistors base [...]*" I understand that you are trying to help give details to readers here. Unfortunately that new info doesn't make sense :-( (a) The RPi GPIO pins can only output 3.3V, not 5V. [+] (b) Even if something did provide 5V to the left side of R1 in your schematic, you should not measure 5V on the right side of R1 (i.e. the transistor's base). ([+] Yes I know an open-collector output could be pulled higher than 3.3V, but that's out-of-spec for the RPi.)